# Rewrite expressions

Tags: logic

I have to prove that

> $$q\lor(¬q\land(p\lor q))$$

is equal to just $q$.

This is normally done with logical equivalences, but I can't solve this one.

Can somebody please help?

----------EDIT----------

So with some help i now got this with the help of a truth table

\begin{array}{|c|c|c|c|} 
\hline p& q & ¬q & p\land q & ¬q\land(p\land q)\\ 
\hline t& t& f& t&f\\ 
 t& f& t& f&f\\ 
 f& t& f& f&f\\ 
 f& f& t& f&f \\\hline
\end{array}

Hence we have

$$\left[q\lor\left(¬q\land(p\land q)\right)\right] \Leftrightarrow \left[q\lor f\right]\Leftrightarrow q.$$

But the assignment is to prove this with logical equivalences. Look it does not matter on my test friday only the answer does. But i can't stand the fact i could not solve this.

We must use the following paper as a cheat sheet https://www.dropbox.coms/o6pau9a3z7yqi39/Logische_equivalenties.docx (Note, not by OP: dead link.)

---------- EDIT ----------

Everyone thanks for the help got an A on the test.

Comment: Am I missing something? If $p$ is true and $q$ is false, then your expression appears to be true.

Comment: Keep applying the distributive properties and using the logical identities outlined in your "cheatsheet".

Comment: In you truth table, the last of the three connectives is $\land$; in the statement of the question it's $\lor$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## *Hint*

Draw a truth table...

You should also note that ands can distribute over ors which leaves you with $q\lor(¬q\land p)$. But then ors can distribute over ands which leaves you with $(q\lor¬q)\land(p\lor q)$ which then further simplifies to $p\lor q\dots$

---

So here is a full take down

Notice that using distributive properties of and over or$$¬q\land(p\lor q)\Leftrightarrow(¬q\land p)\lor(¬q\land q)$$
Now $q$ and $¬q$ is always going to be false and $a$ or false is $a$ so we have $$(¬q\land p)\lor(¬q\land q)\Leftrightarrow (¬q\land p)$$
Next using distributive properties of or over and
$$
q\lor(¬q\land(p\lor q))\Leftrightarrow q\lor(¬q\land p)\Leftrightarrow (q\lor¬q)\land (q\lor p)
$$

Now $q\lor ¬q\Leftrightarrow q$ (you can check with "cheat sheet" or truth table therefore having 
$$ (q\lor¬q)\land (q\lor p)\Leftrightarrow q\land(q\lor p)$$
Finally we have, using distributive properties of and over or
$$q\land(q\lor p)\Leftrightarrow (q\land q) \lor (q\land p)\Leftrightarrow q\lor (q\land p)$$
Now the only way for this statement to be false is if $q$ is false and the converse is true.

Answer (score 2):

Here are two ways to prove that your expression simplifies to $\;p \lor q\;$ (so not to $\;q\;$).

One way is to use distribution and then simplify:
\begin{align}
& q \lor (\lnot q \land (p \lor q)) \\
\equiv & \qquad \text{"$\;\lor\;$ distributes over $\;\land\;$ -- to bring the $\;q\;$'s together"} \\
& (q \lor \lnot q) \land (q \lor p \lor q) \\
\equiv & \qquad \text{"simplify: excluded middle; $\;q \lor q \equiv q\;$"} \\
& \text{true} \land (p \lor q) \\
\equiv & \qquad \text{"simplify"} \\
& p \lor q \\
\end{align}
Here I've not made explicit the associativity and symmetry of $\;\lor\;$.

The other (quicker) way is as follows:
\begin{align}
& q \lor (\lnot q \land (p \lor q)) \\
\equiv & \qquad \text{"use $\;q \equiv \text{false}\;$ on other side of leftmost $\;\lor\;$"} \\
& q \lor (\lnot\text{false} \land (p \lor \text{false})) \\
\equiv & \qquad \text{"simplify"} \\
& q \lor p \\
\end{align}
Personally I find this rule ('assume one side of $\;\lor\;$ is $\;\text{false}\;$ on other side') often useful, just like its dual ('assume one side of $\;\land\;$ is $\;\text{true}\;$ on other side').

Answer (score 1):

As noted by Henning, you cannot prove it.

Assuming that saying that the highlighted formula is equal to $q$ means that :

> $q \equiv (q \lor (\lnot q \land (p \lor q)))$

if we assign to $q$ the value *False*, we have :

> $F \equiv F \lor (\lnot F \land (p \lor F)) \equiv (\lnot F \land (p \lor F))$ --- becuase $F \lor A$ is equivalent to $A$
>
> $\lnot F \land (p \lor F) \equiv T \land (p \lor F) \equiv (p \lor F)$ --- because $T \land A$ is equivalent to $A$.

So we have reduced the problem to :

> $F \equiv (p \lor F)$

and this is not true when $p$ is *True*.

You can check it with a truth-table.

Comment: WOW and i though i just started to get the hang of it. Look i use a online tool from school and have a set of practice expressions. And i can see the answer. So i'm lost